# Posterous API to post to posterous?

Tags: php, symfony1, posterous

I am looking for a (PHP) tutorial that shows how I can programattically post contents of a blog on my site, to my posterous blog.

In case there are no online resources, I will be grateful if someone could post a little snippet in here that shows how this cone be done.

[Edit]

In otherwords, I am looking for an example that posts a sample doc to posterous. I am already aware of libcurl and the git depostory code. What I am looking for is a simple example that shows content being posted - this is simply, so that it saves me from having to go through the documentation (for now), so I can get something up and running ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**libCurl**](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for it.

Answer (score 1):

> this is simply, so that it saves me from having to go through the documentation (for now)

You're better off [just reading the docs](http://apidocs.posterous.com/) yourself. It's a simple RESTful API like many others.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a tutorial, but there is a PHP library on github - http://github.com/calvinf/posterous-api-library-php - for the Posterous API.